# angular2 HostBinding with an Input property

Tags: angular

Is it possible to set the HostBinding with an Input property.  If not what is your approximate solution?

For Ex:

Directive:

```
  @Input('customToggle') target;
  private toggle = false;

  @HostBinding(target) 
  get getToggle() {
    return this.toggle;
  }
```

View:

```
  <li class="dropdown" [customToggle]="class.open">
```

Note how HostBinding has target passed as an argument, how can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way :

```
@HostBinding(target) toggle: boolean = false;
@Input('customToggle') set target(toggle: boolean) {
   this.toggle = toggle;
}
```